# Monodevelop Control + TAB problem

Tags: monodevelop

I am having problem with Monodevelop 2.4 on windows 7 x64. When using Control-Tab to switch between documents a little window pops up with "Pads" on the left and "Documents" on the right side. It stops reacting to any input except mouse (blocking the application completely), it does not disappear until I minimize main window, then restore it and hit Control + TAB again.
I tried downloading and installing mono-2.6.7-gtksharp-2.12.10-win32-2.exe and switching to its runtime with no luck.
Has anybody experienced the same issue?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug pending to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off the "Enable document switch dialog" option in the Visual Style preferences to work around this problem.

Comment: That could be useful, thanks. I personally switched to sharpdevelop and am planning to try MD again when the 2.6 version gets released.